# Decode the Bcrypt encoded password in Spring Security to deactivate user account

Tags: bcrypt, jbcrypt

I am working on web application project in Spring Hibernate MVC. I am storing encoded passwords in a database using Bcrypt algorithm in Spring security.

Now I want to get that encoded password to be decoded to deactivate a use account where in I am giving user email and password to verify before user deactivate the account. I have a problem in getting the decoded password.

Can anyone help me to get out of it or any alternate solution for my requirement?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The problem is solved by using below code:

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();  
encoder.matches(password, user.getPassword());
```

`password` - from form(JSP)
`user.getPassword()` - from database

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
if(email.equalsIgnoreCase(user.getEmail()) && encoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())) {
    userService.deactivateUserByID(user.getId());
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("successmsg", "Your account has been deactivated successfully.");
    model.setViewName("redirect:/logout");
}else{
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errormsg", "Email or Password is incorrect");
    model.setViewName("redirect:/app/profile/deactivate");
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear - this doesn't actually decode the encoded password as implied by the question.  Per the Spring docs, `BCryptPasswordEncoder.matches()` verifies the encoded password obtained from storage matches the submitted raw password after it too is encoded.

Answer (score 7):

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder bcrypt = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();  
boolean isPasswordMatches = bcrypt.matches(userenteredpasswordWithotEncryoted, encryptedPasswordFromDb);
```

Example:

```
boolean isPasswordMatches = bcrypt.matches(
        "Truck123",
        "$2a$10$kcVH3Uy86nJgQtYqAFffZORT9wbNMuNtqytcUZQRX51dx6IfSFEd."
);


if (isPasswordMatches) { // correct password
    ...
} else { // Wrong Password
    ...
}
```